# Cannot run PHP script under Tomcat

Tags: php, tomcat, php-java-bridge

Am using Tomcat 6. I have installed PHP and try to get PHP running inside Tomcat with PHP/JavaBridge. I have deployed JavaBridge.war inside Tomcat's webapps directory. When running any PHP script, I will get this error below. Please help and I thank you for your assistance.

This was how I configure PHP:

> ./configure --with-mime-magic 
>   --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/Zend/etc 
>   --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs 
>   --with-libxml-dir=/usr 
>   --with-mhash=/usr/local 
>   --with-bz2=/usr 
>   --with-curl=/usr 
>   --with-gettext=/usr 
>   --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql 
>   --with-mcrypt=/usr/local 
>   --enable-magic-quotes 
>   --enable-bcmath 
>   --enable-calendar 
>   --enable-ftp 
>   --enable-sockets 
>   --enable-wddx 
>   --enable-mbstring 
>   --enable-zip 
>   --enable-exif 
>   --with-gd=/usr 
>   --with-freetype-dir=/usr 
>   --with-jpeg-dir=/usr 
>   --with-png-dir=/usr 
>   --enable-gd-native-ttf 
>   --enable-fastcgi 
>   --enable-force-cgi-redirect

The error msgs from Tomcat as follows:

> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented
>   it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server
>     php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.init(FastCGIServlet.java:133)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) root cause
>
> php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server
>     php.java.bridge.http.SocketChannelFactory.test(SocketChannelFactory.java:58)
>     php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.init(FastCGIServlet.java:131)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) root cause
>
> java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>     php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException.(FCGIConnectException.java:37)
>     php.java.bridge.http.SocketChannelFactory.test(SocketChannelFactory.java:58)
>     php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.init(FastCGIServlet.java:131)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) root cause
>
> java.io.IOException: PHP not found. Please install php-cgi. PHP test
>   command was: [php-cgi, -v] 
>     php.java.bridge.Util$Process.start(Util.java:1145)
>     php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FCGIProcess.start(FCGIProcess.java:68)
>     php.java.bridge.http.SocketChannelFactory.doBind(SocketChannelFactory.java:125)
>     php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionFactory.runFcgi(FCGIConnectionFactory.java:88)
>     php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionFactory$1.run(FCGIConnectionFactory.java:109)
>   note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/6.0.29 logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/6.0.29

Comment: PHP not found. Please install php-cgi.

Comment: Hi, my configure line did have the --enable-fastcgi. Do I need to add anything extra to enable cgi support? I am quite confused. Please assist. TIA.

Comment: Does this solve it ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728632/php-java-bridge-problem - (-Dphp.java.bridge.php_exec=/usr/bin/php)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error as yours,
the key point you are missing here is :

**PHP CLI**(Command Line Interface) needs to be ***setup*** to work with java-php
 bridge

as you claim to have installed PHP(any means XAMPP/WAMP)

Go through the following steps :

- Add PHP to PATH environment variable - [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22607578/2584794)
- Confirm the configuration by Run CMD>

  ```
  php-cgi -v
  ```
- By the above command you will see  PHP version info
- Restart Tomcat

PHP/JavaBridge should start working after this.

Comment: Just did `apt-get install php-cgi` and `service tomcat8 restart` and the `phpinfo()` started to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Another suggestion had been to add

```
-Dphp.java.bridge.php_exec=/usr/bin/php
```

to the command line.  Instead, I modified the `JAVA_OPTS` export in my `catalina.sh` file to add it.  That didn't work, but I combined it with the suggestion above and added

```
-Dphp.java.bridge.php_exec=/usr/bin/php-cgi
```

to `catalina.sh`.  I bounced the server and connected to server/JavaBridgeTemplate621/ and got the PHP/Java Bridge settings page.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall and enable fastcgi it worked for me!