# PHP/JAVA bridge Tomcat 7 in Solaris 11.2 sparc

Tags: java, php, tomcat7, solaris, php-java-bridge

I have installed PHP 7.0.9 and copied JavaBridge.war file to tomcat7/webapps folder and .jar files on tomcat7/lib folder. Then I restarted the Tomcat server. I found this error:

```
Fatal Error: Failed to start PHP [php-cgi, -v], reason: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "php-cgi" (in directory "/export/home/tomcat"): error=2, No such file or directory
Could not start FCGI server: java.io.IOException: PHP not found. Please install php-cgi. PHP test command was: [php-cgi, -v]
Timeout waiting for PHP FastCGI daemon
php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server
        at php.java.bridge.http.SocketChannelFactory.test(SocketChannelFactory.java:58)
        at php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionPool.<init>(FCGIConnectionPool.java:175)
        at php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionPool.<init>(FCGIConnectionPool.java:189)
        at php.java.servlet.ContextLoaderListener.createConnectionPool(ContextLoaderListener.java:541)
        at php.java.servlet.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException.<init>(FCGIConnectException.java:37)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: PHP not found. Please install php-cgi. PHP test command was: [php-cgi, -v]
        at php.java.bridge.Util$Process.start(Util.java:1145)
        at php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FCGIProcess.start(FCGIProcess.java:68)
        at php.java.bridge.http.SocketChannelFactory.doBind(SocketChannelFactory.java:125)
        at php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionFactory.runFcgi(FCGIConnectionFactory.java:88)
        at php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionFactory$1.run(FCGIConnectionFactory.java:10
9)
```

I am not able to run my PHP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728632/php-java-bridge-problem

Comment: "Fatal Error: Failed to start PHP [php-cgi, -v], reason: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "php-cgi" (in directory "/export/home/tomcat"): error=2, **No such file or directory**"  Seems pretty self-explanatory.  Your installation can't find the command to run.  Where did you install it?

Comment: Check if `php-cgi` is on the `PATH` of the user that runs `tomcat`.

Comment: in .profile i have included the path still the issue                                                   export PATH=/usr/localbin/php-cgi:/export/home/tomcat/php-7.0.9: