# Failed to Start ["php-cgi","-v"]

Tags: tomcat, xampp, php-java-bridge

Im trying to build php-java bridge but i always get error with
"HTTP Status 500 - php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server".

Fatal Error: Failed to start PHP ["php-cgi", "-v"], reason: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""php-cgi"" (in directory "C:\Users\Rob"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
Could not start FCGI server: java.io.IOException: PHP not found. Please install php-cgi. PHP test command was: [php-cgi, -v]

I already read this one [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728632/php-java-bridge-problem) but didnt get how to resolve it

I'm using xampp - tomcat on localhost:8080/JavaBridge

how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `php-cgi` binary is not *technically* required to run the bridge for *regular* PHP->Java interactions... (for Java->PHP it is).

Unfortunately, if you're using the generic `JavaBridgeTemplate.war`, the (Java->PHP) mode is enabled by default and will look for a `php-cgi` executable, which could not be determined *automatically* on your system.

The solution you've [mentionned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728632/php-java-bridge-problem) allows to specify the location of the `php-cgi`executable when using the *integrated* standalone server. But if you use Tomcat, this won't work (not 100% correct, but let's assume it that way)

**So what to do ?**

Under Tomcat, the bridge parameters are stored in a `/WEB-INF/web.xml` file inside the war file. I'll assume you've downloaded and use one from the [sourceforge repo](https://sourceforge.net/projects/php-java-bridge/files/Binary%20package/).

Simply open the `JavaBridgeTemplate<version>.war` file with an archive manager *(a war is pretty much a zip)* and edit the `/WEB-INF/web.xml` with one of the solutions below:

1. **Either completly remove support for Java->PHP.**

This can be achieved by removing the registration of the `PhpCGIServlet` entry. Check for the following xml lines and place comments around (<!-- and -->).

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>PhpCGIServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>PhpCGIServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

*(PS: I'm not totally sure this solution works for all versions of the bridge)*

2. **Or specify the location of the `php-cgi` binary.**

First ensure you have a `php-cgi` executable and take note of its location *(could be `c:/xampp/php/php-cgi.exe` in your case, but I'm not using windows)*. Then look for

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>prefer_system_php_exec</param-name>
    <param-value>On</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Location of your system PHP executable. Default is /usr/bin/php-cgi or c:/Program Files/PHP/php-cgi.exe
     If exported (Linux) or on the path (Windows) you can use 'php-cgi' as a platform
     independent pointer to the executable
-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>php_exec</param-name>
    <param-value>php-cgi</param-value>
    <!-- As an example, the param value
         of the php-cgi executable could be:
            <param-value>/usr/bin/php-cgi5.6</param-value>
            <param-value>/usr/bin/php-cgi7.0</param-value>
            <param-value>c:/Program Files/PHP/php-cgi.exe</param-value>
    -->
</context-param>
```

Ensure that `<param-value>c:/Program Files/PHP/php-cgi.exe</param-value>` contains the location of the `php-cgi`.

---

Then save your changes (be sure the web.xml is well saved in the .war file) and redeploy on your Tomcat server.

Haven't tested but hope it helps.

PS:

- If possible upgrade to Tomcat 7 or 8.
- Note the existence of the [soluble-japha](https://github.com/belgattitude/soluble-japha) reworked client (works with the java bridge server), that'll help a lot ;)